# Как сделать так, что-бы текст начинался в самом начале, а не в середине?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="qww">
    <input class="dd" type="text" placeholder="введите текст">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dd{ 
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    text-align: left;``
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    width: 490px;
    height: 400px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 60px;
    transition: 0.50s;
}

.qww{
    left: 50px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Начать следует с того, чтобы сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен и другим людям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет никакого смысла делать громадный инпут. Для этих целей есть `textarea`

```css
.dd{ 
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 490px;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 60px;
    transition: 0.50s;
    
}

.qww{
    left: 50px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="qww">
   
    <textarea class="dd"  placeholder="введите текст"></textarea>
</div>
```

Правда тут есть небольшая побочка: весь текст тоже будет с паддингом, как и placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

1. input - однострочное поле ввода текста. Если вы задаёте этому полю размеры `width: 490px; height: 400px;`, вы тем самым, располагаете единственную строчку текста строго посередине, относительно рамки (по вертикали). Следует input заменить на textarea, как уже указано в ответе Алексея Шиманского.
2. Свойства left и top указывают блокам при `position: absolute;` или `position: fixed;`. У вас это нет, значит свойства не сработают.
3. Мусор в css: дважды указано свойство border, После `text-align: left;` следует убрать обратные кавычки. Раз у вас цвет текста указан как white - белый, а у самого блока ввода текста указано свойство `background: none;` - убедитесь, что у родительского элемента указан хоть какой-то фоновый цвет, иначе вы получите белый текст на белом фоне.

Доработанный код может выглядеть так:

```css
.dd{ 
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 490px;
    height: 400px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 60px;
    transition: 0.50s;
}
```

```html
<div class="qww">
    <textarea class="dd" type="text" placeholder="введите текст"></textarea>
</div>
```